# Can't plot linear regression predicted model against pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression, forecasting

I am trying to plot a predictive linear regression model against a data frame in pandas using the world bank API. I would like to use the independent variables to feed in and predict GDP growth against the date. More of a forecast but am really struggling. In addition the accuracy score is 1 which is rather strange as that would surely mean it is a perfect prediction? Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
#Connect to world bank api
!pip install wbdata

#Load libraries
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

#Load indicator data
indicators = {"NY.GDP.MKTP.CD": "GDP",
              "NE.CON.PRVT.ZS": "Households and NPISHs Final consumption expenditure (% of GDP)",
              "BX.KLT.DINV.WD.GD.ZS": "Foreign direct investment, net inflows (% of GDP)",
              "NE.CON.GOVT.ZS": "General government final consumption expenditure (% of GDP)",
              "NE.EXP.GNFS.ZS": "Exports of goods and services (% of GDP)",
              "NE.IMP.GNFS.ZS": "Imports of goods and services (% of GDP)" }

#Create dataframe
data = wbdata.get_dataframe(indicators, 
                            country=('GBR'), 
                            data_date=data_dates, 
                            convert_date=False, keep_levels=True)

#Round columns to 2dp
data1 = np.round(data, decimals=2)

#Convert datatype
data1['GDP'] = data1.GDP.astype(float)

#Format digits
data1['GDP'] = data1['GDP'].apply(lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x))

#Reset dataframe indexes
data1.reset_index(inplace=True) 

#Drop unused columns
data1.drop(data1.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)

#Converts all columns in dataframe to float datatypes
data1=data1.astype(float)

#data1.head(11)

#Dependent variable
Y = data1['GDP']

#Independent variable
X = data1[data1.columns[[1,2,3,4,5]]]

#Converts all columns in dataframe to float datatypes
data1=data1.astype(float)

#Create testing and training variables
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1)

#Fit linear model
linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = lm.predict(X_test)

#Plot model
plt.scatter(y_test, predictions)
plt.xlabel('True Values')
plt.ylabel('Predictions')
plt.show()

#Print accuracy scores
accuracy = model.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Accuracy: ", accuracy)
```

Comment: What is data_dates? Your code has a few other errors that make it difficult to run.

Comment: Your test set is too small with only five data points, so it's not incredibly difficult to score an accuracy of 1.

Comment: The data_dates is the year value coming from the world bank api. the code runs fine for me?

Comment: I would like to plot it on the following data1.plot.line(x='date', y='GDP') so the predicted values will be with the actual values?

Comment: ````data_date=data_dates ```` gives me undefined error. Pleas check.

Comment: Also, ````linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()````, linear should be replaced with lm?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541127/pandas-plot-multiple-plot-same-figure

Comment: data_date comes through as an index hence I turned the indexes into columns as I need it to be dynamic. I believe data_date is part of wbdata.get_dataframe?

Comment: Thanks for that I have changed that now :)

Comment: "data_date" is an argument aka part of wbdata.get_dataframe, ````data_dates```` is a variable assigned to it and needs to be defined. If you could show whatever you did to get ````data_dates```` that would help.

Comment: I got it from here: http://wbdata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wbdata.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176275/discussion-between-xyzjayne-and-ryan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was run and multiple issues were identified.

1. OP wanted to plot predicted y values against `date` of `x_test`.

As a result of this line: `X = data1[data1.columns[[1,2,3,4,5]]]`

`x_test` does not contain `date` (column 0) anymore. Run `train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1)` with `X`containing `date` to get the correct dates associated with each data point, and run the linear model with a copy of x_test with this column dropped (because date is not an independent variable).

2. High accuracy is due to the inclusion of dependent variable in independent variables.

`X = data1[data1.columns[[1,2,3,4,5]]]` actually contains 'GDP' and omits another possible independent variable. The recommended way would be explicitly dropping 'GDP' from the data.

3. Plotting a line chart with Pandas and a scatter plot in the same graph

OP wanted a line plot of actual GDP against year: `data1.plot.line(x='date', y='GDP')`, and later a scatter plot `plt.scatter(X_test['date'], predictions)`. To do this, define an axes object with `subplots` and plot both on the same subplot.

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()
data1.plot.line(x='date', y='GDP', ax = ax)
ax.scatter(X_test['date'], predictions)
plt.show()
```